# TSC compiler error: async funtion reqires 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript, promise, tsconfig

I have googled this error and every post i read tells me to add 'es2015' in the lib option, tsconfig file. I have tried this but it does not work. I've also tried to use `esModuleInterop` to get rid of my export error. It almost feels like the compiler doesn´t care about my changes in the config file.
I would appreciate some help.

```
error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.

RaspiClient.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"socket.io-client"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

1 import io from 'socket.io-client';
         ~~

  node_modules/@types/socket.io-client/index.d.ts:9:5
    9     export = io;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

RaspiClient.ts:23:34 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' 
option.

23 const setVideoTracks = async (): Promise<Event> => {
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

RaspiClient.ts:56:25 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' 
option.

56     const createOffer = async () => {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

RaspiClient.ts:71:28 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' 
option.

71       const createAnswer = async (sdp: RTCSessionDescription) => {
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

RaspiClient.ts:109:33 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.

109       socket.on("getCandidate", async (candidate: RTCIceCandidate) => {
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
}
```

And this is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const SOCKET_SERVER_URL = "hhtp//192.168.1.242:8080"

const pc_config: RTCConfiguration = {
    iceServers: [
        // {
        //   urls: 'stun:[STUN_IP]:[PORT]',
        //   'credentials': '[YOR CREDENTIALS]',
        //   'username': '[USERNAME]'
        // },
        {
          urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
        },
    ],
};

const pc: RTCPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io.connect(SOCKET_SERVER_URL);

let localVideo: HTMLVideoElement;

const setVideoTracks = async () => {
  try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: true,
      });

      if(localVideo) localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      if(!(pc && socket)) return;

      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          console.log("Adding local media track");
          if(!pc) return;
          pc.addTrack(track, stream)
      });

      pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
          if(e.candidate) {
              if(!socket) return;
              console.log("onicecandidate");
              socket.emit("candidate", e.candidate);
          }
      };
      const stats = await pc.getStats();
      console.dir(stats);
      socket.emit("join_room", {
          room: "VID_STREAM_1"
      });
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
};

const createOffer = async () => {
    console.log("create offer");
    if(!(pc && socket)) return;
    try {
      const sdp = await pc.createOffer({
        offerToReceiveAudio: true,
        offerToReceiveVideo: true
      });
      await pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
      socket.emit("offer", sdp)
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const createAnswer = async (sdp: RTCSessionDescription) => {
    if(!(pc && socket)) return;
    try {
      await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
      console.log("answer set remote description success");
      const mySdp = await pc.createAnswer({
        offerToReceiveVideo: true,
        offerToReceiveAudio: true,
      });
      console.log("create answer");
      await pc.setLocalDescription( new RTCSessionDescription(mySdp));
      socket.emit("answer", mySdp);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  socket.on("all_users", (allUsers: Array<{id:string}>) => {
    if(allUsers.length > 0) {
      createOffer();
    } else {
        pc.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    console.log("all_users")
  });

  socket.on("getOffer", (sdp: RTCSessionDescription) => {
    console.log("get offer")
    createAnswer(sdp);
  });

  socket.on("getAnswer", (sdp: RTCSessionDescription) => {
    console.log("get answer");
    if(!pc) return;
    pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp);
  });

  socket.on("getCandidate", async (candidate: RTCIceCandidate) => {
    if(!pc) return;
    try {
      await pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
      console.log("Candidate add success")
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });

  setVideoTracks();
```

Comment: I'm new to TS, but I believe you simply need to annotate all your async functions with `Promise<T>` (if returning some type `T`) or `Promise<void>` if not returning a value. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: `lib` should be in `compilerOptions`